# Resource intensive multithreading killing other processes

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, brute-force

I have a very resource intensive code, that I made, so I can split the workload over multiple pthreads. While everything works, the computation is done faster, etc. What I'm guessing happens is that other processes on that processor core get so slow, that they crash after a few seconds of runtime.

I already managed to kill random processes like Chrome tabs, the Cinnamon DE or even the entire OS (Kernel?).

Code: (It's late, and I'm too tired to make a pseudo code, or even comments..)
-- But it's a brute force code, not so much for cracking, but for testing passwords and or CPU IPS.

Any ideas how to fix this, while still keeping as much performance as possible?

```
static unsigned int   NTHREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
static int            THREAD_COMPLETE = -1;
static std::string    PASSWORD = "";
static std::string    CHARS;
static std::mutex     MUTEX;

void *find_seq(void *arg_0)
{
  unsigned int _arg_0 =   *((unsigned int *) arg_0);
  std::string *str_CURRENT =  new std::string(" ");

  while (true)
  {
    for (unsigned int loop_0 = _arg_0; loop_0 < CHARS.length() - 1; loop_0 += NTHREADS)
    {
      str_CURRENT->back() = CHARS[loop_0];

      if (*str_CURRENT == PASSWORD)
      {
        THREAD_COMPLETE = _arg_0;
        return (void *) str_CURRENT;
      }
    }

    str_CURRENT->back() = CHARS.back();

    for (int loop_1 = (str_CURRENT->length() - 1); loop_1 >= 0; loop_1--)
    {
      if (str_CURRENT->at(loop_1) == CHARS.back())
      {
        if (loop_1 == 0)
          str_CURRENT->assign(str_CURRENT->length() + 1, CHARS.front());
        else
        {
          str_CURRENT->at(loop_1) =     CHARS.front();
          str_CURRENT->at(loop_1 - 1) = CHARS[CHARS.find(str_CURRENT->at(loop_1 - 1)) + 1];
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The symptoms you describe are those of an  out of memory situation caused by a memory or resource leak, invoking the [oom killer](https://www.memset.com/docs/additional-information/oom-killer/)

Comment: @kfsone Sounds likely, but the application uses 20MB at most, and Valgrind reports the following: possibly lost: 2,223 bytes in 14 blocks && still reachable: 56 bytes in 7 blocks. Of course, there are some leaks that I will try to fix, but sometimes Valgrind gives innacurate data.

Comment: A process that hogs CPU should not be able to crash other processes, ever. It will slow them down, but can only crash them due to faulty hardware or a kernel bug.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I've already posted my answer to the problem below. I have to wait until I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers and especially Matthew Fisher for his suggestion to try it on another system.

---

After some trial and error I decided to pull back my CPU overclock that I thought was stable (I had it for over a year) and that solved this weird behaviour. I guess that I've never ran such a CPU intensive and (I'm guessing) efficient (In regards to not throttling the full CPU by yielding) script to see this happen.

As Matthew suggested I need to come up with a better way than to just constantly check the THREAD_COMPLETE variable with a `while true` loop, but I hope to resolve that in the comments.

Full and updated code for future visitors is here: [pastebin.com/jbiYyKBu](http://pastebin.com/jbiYyKBu)

Answer (score 1):

Areuz,

Can you post the full code?  I suspect the issue is the NTHREADS value.  On my Ubuntu box, the value is set to 8 which is the number of cores in the /proc/cpuinfo file.  Kicking off 8 'hot' threads on my box hogs 100% of the CPU. The kernel will time slice for its own critical processes but in general all other processes will starve for CPU.

Check out the max processor value in /etc/cpuinfo and go at least one lower then that.  The CPU's are numbered 0-7 on my box, so 7 would be the max for me.  The actual max might be 3 since 4 of my cores are hyper-threads. For completely CPU processes, hyper-threading generally doesn't help.

Bottom line, don't hog all the CPU, it will destabilize the system.

--Matt

Comment: I have a i7 3770K @ 4.8GHz. It has 8 threads. I obviously tried to use all the threads for increased performance. I'm just wondering why something like the 'stress' command can use all of the CPU without crashing anything.

P.S. Even If I use just a few threads, the processes that are being run on those threads, as I stated, some of my Chrome tabs, etc. will most of the time crash over time.

Full code, just for good measure: http://pastebin.com/jbiYyKBu

Comment: I decided to look at the 'stress' source code, and I'm even more confused now. I can stress the whole cpu, all day long, with it, so I expected some kind of sophisticated code, to sleep for some time, or just lower the priority. But the literal code for stressing cpu with that command is: 
`hogcpu (void) 
{
  while (1)
    sqrt (rand ());

  return 0;
}`

Comment: Hmm, no joy.  I ran the code locally with no problem.  It maxed out my 8 cores but the box was still functioning fine. I ran for about 20 minutes with no problems.   Ubuntu 14.04.  Can you try on another box?  AWS has free accounts.

As a minor note, the while loop in main is running hot using another core.  pthread_join can be used to monitor if a thread exits. The THREAD_COMPLETE can be used as a flag for the threads to exit rather than while(1)

Comment: It's not quite finished, the THREAD_COMPLETE will be used as a flag for threads to exit. Also, I have the workload spread, so that only 1 thread will return the result. I would have to use `pthread_tryjoin_np` to check all threads to see which one finished, but I want my code to be portable across OS's. As you see by the `_np`, the command is non-portable.

Comment: Indeed, on my other machine running the same distro I could not recreate this behaviour. I'll look more into it tommorow, but the problem with `pthread_tryjoin_np` still remains...